# Creating multiple line input in different lines in python 3

Tags: python, input, line

I want to create a program that takes number of inputs from user but in different lines.
First, it asks for number of numbers (which will be the number of lines):

```
number_of_lines=int(input("Please enter a number of numbers (1-5) "))
```

then it has to ask for input from a user in new lines, something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAXXI.png)

how can i do it ? thank  you:)

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
inputs = []
for i in range(number_of_lines):
    n=int(input())
    inputs.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the variable `number_of_lines` you can define the following loop:

```
inputs = [int(input() for i in range(number_of_lines)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The number must be between 1 and 5
number_of_lines=int(input("Please enter a number of numbers (1-5) :"))
while (number_of_lines > 5) or (number_of_lines < 1):
    number_of_lines=int(input("Please enter a number of numbers (1-5) :"))

# Enter number
print("Please enter the numbers,one in each line")
Result=[]
for i in range(0,number_of_lines):
    Result.append(int(input()))
```